# Return more than 1 value from JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How we can return more than one values from JavaScript function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just return an object.

```
return { a:1, b:2 };
```

Answer (score 2):

You could return an array:

```
function() {
    return [a, b];
}
```

Or an object:

```
function() {
    return {a: a, b: b};
}
```

Or assign values to an input:

```
function(ref) {
    ref.a = a;
    ref.b = b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To return more than one value, *you have **two** options*: `Array` or an `Object`:

```
// return array
return ['foo', 'bar'];

// return object
return {"foo" : "hey foo", "bar" : "hey bar"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to return a JavaScript Object for example

Do all you calculations and logic and then put them in an object
like `{'x':3,'y':4}` etc and `return  {'x':3,'y':4}`

Answer (score 1):

Also I want to refer to destructuring assignment which is quite a new feature (so probably not what you want to use).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7

In paragraph `Destructuring assignment` you get a good impression of how this task my be tackled in the future.